# didSelectItemAtIndexPath modifying multiple cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have collection view with 30 items, and want to perform something on press. I do it in this way:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ItemCell

    var translucentView = ILTranslucentView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height))
    translucentView.translucentAlpha = 0.9
    translucentView.translucentStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    translucentView.translucentTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    translucentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    translucentView.alpha = 0.0
    cell.contentView.addSubview(translucentView)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        translucentView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

The function works as expected, however the view appears not only on the tapped cell, but also on the cell in the same position that is not visible on the screen.
So if there are 3 visible cells on the screen and I tap on number 1, then when I scroll the view has been added to cell 4, 7, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` re-use cells like to `UITableView`. When a cell is scrolled offscreen it is added to queue, and will be re-used for the next cell to be scrolled onscreen(e.g. cell 4, 7 ...).

Simply removing the `translucentView` will solve this issue:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
    translucentView.alpha = 1.0
}) { (finish) -> Void in
    translucentView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

You can create the `translucentView` in the `ItemCell` and update its status in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    if find(collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as! [NSIndexPath], indexPath) != nil {
        cell.translucentView.alpha = 1.0
    } else {
        cell.translucentView.alpha = 0.0
    }

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ItemCell

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        cell.translucentView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ItemCell

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        cell.translucentView.alpha = 0.0
    })
}
```

Comment: The translucentView should remain there at all times until the user presses again on the cell. It can disappear when the user scrolls and that cell is not visible anymore.

Comment: Are you allowing multiple selection on the `CollectionView`?

Comment: No, but what does that have to do with the view being added to multiple cells?

Comment: You have to create the `translucentView` and update its status in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, then you can animate it in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: The translucentView has to be placed on the cell only when the cell has been selected, and has to be removed when the user pressed on another cell. It's not a matter of animation, that is just to make it look nice. If I create it cellForItemAtIndexPath then it will give the same effect

Comment: The important thing, as Bannings points out, is that you must modify your cell in one place only, and that is in cellForItemAtIndexPath. If you modify it elsewhere in a way that cellForItemAtIndexPath is not aware of, you _will_ run into the kind of problem that you found, because other rows _will_ use the cell that you modified.

Answer (score 0):

did you set your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` correctly like that?

```
 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int      {
    return 1
}
```